# Jquery height animation bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I can't post my entire source because it is huge but maybe someone can shed some light because I''m sure this happens other places as well.

I have a DIV with rounded edges, using jquery the div toggles between two heights when clicked.

Oddly enough, it is really on on the right side, the div gets a few pixles on the right chopped off as the DIV grows or shrinks. Making the div appear thinner and the bottom right corner becomes sharp (due to the par that was rounded being cut off). As soon as the animation is complete, the

I am trying to have a smooth animation and this is very distracting.

Current state of project

http://eyerislabs.com/CurrentProject/

Comment: Can you create a SSCCE on jsfiddle?

Comment: Have you set a fixed width on this div? Without code I'm sure everyone will be at a loss as to the problem.

Comment: I will need to upload the site as it is now, it uses Bootstrap so, it's slightly too complicated for Jsfiddle. 
http://eyerislabs.com/CurrentProject/

Comment: It's quite of hard to help you if you post the entirely site, my recommendation it's just load and example of your div and your event handler when you do the animation in `jsfiddle`

Comment: If your problem is the unsmooth transition while transition, I recommend you to calculate your width before toggle transition and apply that during transition.

Answer (score 0):

try this

live fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dqWqT/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="main_div">
    <span class="div_title">Which is your favourite car brand ? </span>
    <ul class="inner_list">
        <li>Car1</li>
        <li>Car2</li>
        <li>Car3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="main_div">
    <span class="div_title">Which is your favourite food ? </span>
    <ul class="inner_list">
        <li>food1</li>
        <li>food2</li>
        <li>food3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main_div{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px dotted green;
    width:275px;
}

.div_title{
    font-size:15px;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".inner_list").hide();
$(".main_div").click(function(){
    $(".inner_list", this).slideToggle("slow");
});
```